# Getting the last bit of string before the whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

So say I have the following strings...

```
"AUDI A4, S4, RS4 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  95-01"
"AUDI 80, 90 4DR SEDAN  86-"
"AUDI A6, 100 QUATTRO 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  92-"
"AUDI A4, S4 (B6,B7) QUATTRO 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  01-08"
```

I basically want to get the last digits from the string in JavaScript like...

It would be even better if I could split the string into an array or strings.

```
"95-01"
"86-"
"92-"
"01-08"
```

Does anyone know how this is possible? I know how to do it from the start like...

```
str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')); 
str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1);
```

However i'm not sure how to get the end :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split on whitespace character and get last element as bunch of digits that you want.

```
var arr =  str.split(' ');
var digits = arr[arr.length-1];
```

Comment: Care to elaborate the downvote? This, together with the answer from Waqar Ul Aziz, should work fine.

Comment: Not enough jQuery? (Seriously though, people who downvote working answers never seem to explain.)

Answer (score 2):

```
str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `split` function:

```
str.split(' ');
```

This will return an array. The last element of the array will be the digits.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
str.replace(/^.* /, '')
```

Replace everything up through a space (which will be the last space, since by default regular expressions are "greedy") with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam91Holt you can do it with the help of split and splice function() like:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var data = "AUDI A4, S4, RS4 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  95-01";
            console.log(data.split(" ").splice(-1));
        });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>



  </body>

</html>
```

By this way you can resolve your problem. this above is working one, try this (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substr` function on the string to get the last digits i.e. part of the string.

```js
var str = "AUDI A4, S4 (B6,B7) QUATTRO 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  01-08";
var index = str.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;
var value = str.substring(index);

console.log(value);
```

Suppose you have the strings in the form of an array of strings from which you want to get the digits part then you could do the following to prepare the digits string array.

Using JavaScript

```js
var arr = [ "AUDI A4, S4, RS4 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  95-01",
"AUDI 80, 90 4DR SEDAN  86-",
"AUDI A6, 100 QUATTRO 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  92-",
"AUDI A4, S4 (B6,B7) QUATTRO 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  01-08" ];

var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var value = arr[i];
  var index = value.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;
  numbers.push(value.substring(index));
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Using jQuery

```js
var arr = [ "AUDI A4, S4, RS4 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  95-01",
"AUDI 80, 90 4DR SEDAN  86-",
"AUDI A6, 100 QUATTRO 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  92-",
"AUDI A4, S4 (B6,B7) QUATTRO 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  01-08" ];

var numbers = [];
$.map(arr, function(value, index) {
  var index = value.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;
  numbers.push(value.substring(index));
});

console.log(numbers);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). Example in snippet below.

```js
var str = "AUDI A4, S4, RS4 4DR SEDAN, WAGON  95-01"
var myArray = str.split(' '); 
var lastEntry = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
console.log(lastEntry);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with the code provided?